# place a delay (5 sec) at the end of a looping time line (2 loops). Flash action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

Im new to action script 3 and am just starting to understand it a bit. Im trying to create a loop with a delay in it but am not having much luck!!! I have two codes in my last frame of my timeline, but jus cant get them to work together. Can this be done!

```
//Pause timeline for 5 seconds

stop();
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){play(),clearInterval(myInterval)}, 5000);

trace(myInterval);


//Loop Function - twice

if (!loopCount) {
  var loopCount:Number = 0;
}
loopCount++;
if (loopCount >= 2) {
  this.stop();
}

trace(loopCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you very well, but if you want to play a MovieClip in loop 2 times and then add a 5 seconds delay you can try something like:

```
 const MAX_LOOPS:uint = 2;
 var numLoops:uint = 0;

 myMovieClip.addFrameScript(myMovieClip.totalFrames-1, loopControlHandler);
 var myInterval:uint;

 function intervalHandler():void
 {
     myMovieClip.play();
     clearInterval(myInterval);
 }

 function loopControlHandler():void
 {
    numLoops++;
    if(numLoops == MAX_LOOPS)
    {
        myMovieClip.stop();
        numLoops = 0;
        myInterval = setInterval(intervalHandler, 5000);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, gPeart that is what I was aiming for. This is great Thanks.